# Is there any equivalent in jquery for prototype serialize()

Tags: jquery, forms, prototypejs

I am trying to pass form's data to **jquery ajax request**. i find easy way for prototype **$('formid').serialize()** which will reqturn a string with all elements name and their value inside that form, ready for ajax request in a handy way. that's easy.

so is there any equivalent in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's the same:
http://api.jquery.com/serialize