# What would be the jQuery equivalent of this Prototype Ajax invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

In Prototype, this Ajax call posts its form to the server as a URL encoded string of name-value pairs, as you would find in a HTTP GET request:

```
function doajax()
{
 var current_req = new Ajax.Request('/doajax', {
 asynchronous:true, 
 evalScripts:true,
 parameters: $('ajax_form').serialize(true)}
 );
}
```

How would you do the same thing using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the default `method` for `Ajax.Request` is POST, the equivalent [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call would look like this:

```
function doajax()
{
  $.post('/doajax', $('#ajax_form').serialize(), function(respose) {
    //do something with response if needed
  });
}
```

If you don't need/don't care about the response, this will do:

```
function doajax()
{
  $.post('/doajax', $('#ajax_form').serialize());
}
```

Or, if you're specifically fetching a script, then it'll look like this, using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
function doajax()
{
  $.ajax({
    url:'/doajax', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function(respose) {
      //do something with response if needed
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Serialize in jquery vs prototype is only equivalent if there is no parameter, but when in prototype it is `true`, the function returns an object instead of a string. Since the OP needs the result from `.serialize(true)`, the jquery's version of `.serialize()` is not going to produce the same result. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414271/is-there-any-equivalent-in-jquery-for-prototype-serialize) and [here](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/serialize/) for details. I don't know however, if the request would work by assigning the string instead of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) ajax request, and [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)-ing the form:

```
$.get({
  url: '/doajax', 
  data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(),
  success: function (data) {//success request handler
  }
})
```